# Understanding math used to determine if vector is clockwise / counterclockwise from your vector

Tags: mathematics, vector

I'm reading Programming Game AI by Example by Mat Buckland.  In the Math & Physics primer chapter there's a listing of the declaration of a class used to represent 2D vectors.

This class contains a method called Sign. It's implementation is as follows

```
//------------------------ Sign ------------------------------------------
//
//  returns positive if v2 is clockwise of this vector,
//  minus if anticlockwise (Y axis pointing down, X axis to right)
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
enum {clockwise = 1, anticlockwise = -1};

inline int Vector2D::Sign(const Vector2D& v2)const
{
  if (y*v2.x > x*v2.y)
  { 
    return anticlockwise;
  }
  else 
  {
    return clockwise;
  }
}
```

Can someone explain the vector rules that make this hold true?

What do the values of y*v2.x and x*v2.y that are being compared actually represent?

I'd like to have a solid understanding of why this works rather than just accepting that it does without figuring it out.  I feel like it's something really obvious that I'm just not catching on to.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It looks like it's looking at the sign of the cross product, which would be `x * v2.y - y * v2.x`.  When the cross product is negative, `y * v2.x > x * v2.y`.

Comment: I think I've found a page that describes what's being done:
http://www.oocities.org/pcgpe/math2d.html

The section entitled 'Clockwise/Anticlockwise'.

At the bottom of that section they have the following:

if ((E1x * E2y - E1y * E2x) >= 0) clockwise = TRUE; 
else clockwise = FALSE;

If the E1Y * 2x is brought over to the other side of the equation you have a very similar comparison.  And once you account for the fact that they are using a coordinate system in which +Y goes up, rather than down as stated in the code snippet, I think it's pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let's first discuss the dot product. **A**·**B** is a measure of **A**'s component in the direction of **B** or vice versa; of the magnitudes of both vectors as well as their similarity in direction. Vectors pointing in the same direction have a dot product equal to the product of their lengths, perpendicular vectors have a dot product of zero. Turn the vectors even further apart, and the dot product becomes negative. Though normally defined as *(x,y)·(u,v) = xu + yv*, it has the property: ***A***·**B** = A B cos θ, where θ is the angle between the two vectors.

The sign of this product can be used to determine whether a vector **B** partly points in the same or opposing direction of a reference vector **A**, i.e. if **A**·**B** is positive, the angle is less than 90° (or greater than -90°). It doesn't tell us if the vector points left or right with respect to the reference. Below is a graphical description. Blue vectors **B** would yield a positive **A**·**B**, red vectors a negative.

[image: Vector diagram 1]

We do have this information we want if we carry out the dot product of **B** and a different reference vector: **A** rotated ninety degrees clockwise (we'll call it **A'**). Once again, in blue vectors **B** that would yield a positive **A'**·**B**, negative values in red.

[image: Vector diagram 2]

Note that in a coordinate system with the x-axis pointing right and the y-axis pointing down, we can rotate a vector 90° clockwise as *(x,y)' = (-y,x)*, ergo: ***A'***·**B** = (x,y)'·(u,v) = (-y,x)·(u,v) = -yu + xv. This number is positive (**B** is clockwise of **A**) if *x v > y u*. Those are exactly the two values your code is comparing.

Comment: I could be wrong but I think (-y,x) yields a counter clockwise rotation and (y,-x) yields a clockwise rotation by 90 degrees.
`(-y,x) = (1,1) == (-1,1)`
`(y,-x) = (1,1) == (1,-1)`

Comment: and thanks for a detailed answer. I keep reinventing the wheel when it comes time to rotate an object in the direction the user clicked. This makes so much sense to me now I wish I could give you 10 upvotes.

Comment: @AlexBrown: Assuming the x-axis points right and the y-axis points up, _(-y,x)_ is indeed the counter-clockwise rotation of _(x,y)_. However, the question uses a coordinate system in which the y-axis points down. That's easily overlooked though. I will add it to my answer for completeness. Thanks.

Comment: I see it now in the comments of the code. I knew I was missing something ;)